# Probability of drawing particular card first

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Probability of drawing a card from a deck of $52$ cards is $1/52$.
But if I want to calculate a probability of drawing two cards where first one is a specific one (e.g. Ace of Clubs).

**So there are $52!/(2!(52-2)!) = 1326$ ways to draw two cards.**
There are $\textbf{51}$ way to draw two cards where first one - is a **Ace of Clubs.**

So why $51/1326$  doesn't equal to $1/52$? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I suppose, that's because binomial coefficient gives you a number of draws without considering their specific order (see 2! in deminator). this means that you are NOT drawing a specific card first, but rather you can draw it either first or second

Comment: @guest Can you explain it more clearly? Why shouldn't I have 2! in denominator? Why do I care about order here if I want to receive all possible combinations of 2 cards

Comment: "Why do I care about order?" You care about order because that is the only way you can talk about the **first** card.

Comment: @MikeEarnest so how should I calculate it then?

Comment: @Vanconts just don't use 2! in the denomiator and you'll get the result with order taken into account. If you need some fancy term for that it's called "permutation" or "$k$-permutation on $n$" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n), defined as $P(n,k)=n!/(n-k)!$. In your case $P(52,2)=52!/(52-2)!=52\times 51$.

Comment: @guest Yeah thanks, now I know the difference between permutations and combinations. I don't know should I create another question, I want to understand now how to approach 1/51 probability of drawing specific as SECOND one. It's clear that it's 1/51, but if I take a sample space of size 52x51 and have the same size of Event (51 samples) I get 51/2652  which equals to 1/52. Mb I should somehow care about probability of NOT drawing specific card as first?

Comment: @Vanconts , I think the probability is not $1/51$. consider, you think of a specific card and you want to draw it on the second draw. It may happen, that you draw it on the first draw, so there is a $1/52$ chance that you removed it and physically can't draw once again. Thus the probability that second draw is meaningful $51/52$. Now on the second draw you want one card out of $51$ thus $1/51$ probabily. Multiplication yields $51/52 \times 1/51 = 1/52$.

Answer (score 2):

When you talk of ace of clubs being first, you are considering the order in which cards are being drawn.

In general, there will thus  be $52\times51$ ways in which two cards can be drawn.

Against this, drawing ace of clubs followed by some other has $1\times 51$ ways,
which resolves your anomaly.

Comment: I want to understand it in terms of sets. Set A consist of all possible draws of 2 cards where first card is Ace of Clubs. Uniform probability distribution says that P(A) = A/U, where U = all possible outcomes.

Comment: @Vanconts Your computation of $51$ ways out of $1326$ to get the Ace:Clubs plus some other card included having the other card come first.  Notice that $$\frac{51}{1326} = \frac{1}{26} = \frac{2}{52}.$$

Comment: Re previous comment, so the probability of drawing two cards, and having one of the two cards be the Ace:Clubs is in fact $$\frac{2}{52}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 but why? Chance of drawing Ace:Clubs is 1/51, Second card can be any card so it should not affect probability, so it must be 1/51

Comment: @Vanconts: By definition, a set is an unordered group of elements, i.e. the order of elements in a set does not matter, So you instead need to use  tuples, where order matters.

Comment: @trueblueanil I mean I want to understand it in terms of sample space and events

Comment: @Vanconts: The sample space  has $52\times51$ equiprobable sample points (which are tuples), and the event is ace of clubs followed by any other which occupies $1\times$51$ sample points in the sample space. Think of how dice experiments are treated. Problems there present a large variety of events.

Comment: @trueblueanil why 52x51? Isn't it combination of 2 cards without replacement in deck of 52 cards, so must be 52!/(2!(52-2)!) = 1326 where n = 52, and k = 2. I understand it as I have ALL possible combinations of 2 cards(without repeat), and subset where I have Ace:Clubs first(51 outcome). Why it is not right?

Comment: Again and again we are going round and round. I suggest you look at it from Pr viewpont, it is simpler to understand. Ace of clubs followed by one other, Pr $= \frac1{52}\frac{51}{51}$  But Ace of club and another in two cards $= \Large\frac{\binom11\binom{51}1}{\binom{52}2}$

Answer (score 0):

For the sample space $52\cdot51$, we ask the question

> How many outcomes start with the Ace of Clubs, answer $51$.

For the sample space $\binom{52}{2}$, we ask the question

> How many outcomes contain the Ace of Clubs, answer $51$.

They are the same.

Comment: In the second case why 51? Ace of Clubs can be on the first place as well as on the second, so must be 102

Comment: @Vanconts; there are only $51$ cards it can pair with.

Comment: yes, and there can be 51 pair of cards where it on the first place, and 51 where it is on the second place

Comment: @Vanconts; that's the first sample space (ordered), the binomial returned the number of unordered pairs.

Comment: I’m not familiar with binomial sample spaces, book I’m reading now (All of statistics, Wassermann) didn’t describe such topic yet. Could you explain please?

Comment: @Vanconts; If we have $4$ cards $ABCD$, then the first space is $AB,AC,AD,BA,BC,BD,CA,CB,CD,DA,DB,DC$ and the second is a subset $AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$.

Comment: so you want to say that second case you mentioned is binomial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143072/discussion-between-jmp-and-vanconts).

Comment: You select 1st card : 52 options. Then you select 2nd card : 51 options. Total = 52x51 options. End of computation. You need to know which card was selected first so you need to consider that A+B is different from B+A. When you consider that A+B is same as B+A, you need to divide by 2, or with mathematical words, you can use Binomials. Here, your division by 2 is not relevant.  If you look in detail your formula $52!/2!(52-2)!$, it is $52*51/2$